# MYSQL LIKE clause returning nothing?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a database with a column called item_name. I am trying to pull data out of my database using keywords in my item_name column using the LIKE clause but am getting nothing returned. Is there something wrong with my code below? I have tried commas and AND instead of the OR but still no results.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT category, item_name, link, price, pic, retailer FROM products WHERE item_name LIKE ('%gtx%') OR ('%video%') OR ('%sound%') ORDER BY id DESC");

$query = ($sql) or die (mysql_error());

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
```

Comment: you need to repeat the column name and LIKE after OR as far as i know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify the `LIKE` after each `OR`

```
SELECT category, item_name, link, price, pic, retailer 
FROM products 
WHERE item_name LIKE ('%gtx%') 
    OR item_name LIKE ('%video%') 
    OR item_name LIKE ('%sound%') 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
    WHERE(item_name '%gtx%' OR item_name LIKE '%video%' OR item_name LIKE '%sound%')

. I think this would run. Did you test your query directly in mysql interface?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `LIKE` after each `OR`, so the SQL setence will be like this:

```
SELECT category, item_name, link, price, pic, retailer FROM products 
WHERE item_name LIKE ('%gtx%') 
      OR item_name LIKE ('%video%') 
      OR item_name LIKE ('%sound%') 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Because in the old sentence, without LIKE the database doesn't understand the ('%video%') term like a logic value.